# How to pass locales in simple_fields_for partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, nested-forms, nested-attributes, simple-form-for

I have the following code in My View:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= simple_fields_for :profile do |p| %>
   <%= render 'profile_fields', f => p %>
 <% end %>
 <%= f.submit %>
```

So I was trying to pass locales for 'profile_fields' partial the following way and am trying access that locale in partial, it was throwing an error like "Undefined method type".

```
<%= simple_fields_for :profile do |p| %>
 <%= render 'profile_fields', f => p, :type => "Test" %>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this,

```
<%= render 'profile_fields', f => p, :type => "Test" %>
```

with

```
<%= render 'profile_fields', :locals => {:f=> p, :test=> "Test"} %>
```